# Creating an instance of a class dynamically with results from mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysqli

Problem: The printf is working, but I am not getting the name from the object. I want to generate instances of a class once my results from a mySQL database come back using foreach loop. I think I need to use variable variables. I prefer the syntax of

```
${'class' . $var} // only ever heard of $$var syntax but saw this on SO
```

What I've got...

```
include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
    include 'class/User.php'; // class has two fields... name and email with
                              // getter = getName

    if(!$conn){
        die("connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    } // connection is successful
    $sql = "SELECT user_name As Name, user_email As Email FROM users;"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $rows = array();
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $i= 1;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
            printf ("Name: %s\n Email: %s\n\n", $row["Name"], $row["Email"]);

            ${'user' . $i} = new User();
            ${'user' . $i}->setName($row['Name']);
            echo $pattern1->name();
            $i++;
        }
```

Am I on the right path? Please help me out here. As always, I'm a learning beginner, and I love to hear advice to expand my understanding. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: Not getting any output from the object. Printf works as expected

Comment: I don't actually understand, is the `${'user' . $i}` variable not created? if so do a `var_dump(${'user' . $i})` and see the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you have variables like `$var1`, `$var2` you should probably be using an array.  It would be simpler to do something like

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf ("Name: %s\n Email: %s\n\n", $row["Name"], $row["Email"]);

    $newUser = new User();
    $newUser->setName($row['Name']);
    $newUser->setEMail($row['Email']);
    $rows[] = $newUser;
}
```

This will create the `$rows` array with a list of User objects in a cleaner way.

You can access it in a loop using

```
foreach ( $users as $user) {
    echo $user->getName();
}
```

Comment: So if I want the second user's email... would I echo $rows[1][1];

Comment: The second user will be `$rows[1]`, so if you have getter methods it would be something like `$rows[1]->getEMail()`

Comment: Just to make it more legible - you would probably be better to rename the `$rows` array to `$users`

Comment: I see... it accesses the object stored in the first index and then runs the getter method to retrieve that object's field. Thanks. I greatly appreciate your explanations.

Comment: I got an error:    Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object. The line it references is the first call... echo $users[i]->getName(); inside my for loop

Comment: That would most likely be that it should be `echo $users[$i]->getName();` (missing $ before i)- although I'll add example of a `foreach`

Comment: Thanks for offering the example. That would be helpful. Ahhh I see it lol... Sorry, I'm coming from C#. Thanks for spotting it for me.